# A specific 301 redirection to another domain via htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

There are a lot of answers here at Stack Overflow regarding the redirection via htaccess and I have some basic understanding about this. Instead of redirecting the same paths to the new domain, I need these results:

1. Redirect both olddomain.com and www.olddomain.com to hxxps://www.newdomain.com
2. Redirect www.olddomain.com/example-page to hxxps://www.newdomain.com/somepage

Please note in condition 2 that I want to redirect the subpages to different paths on new domain. The first part is easy for me but the second one challenges me. How can I achieve these results (for 301 redirect)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?olddomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ https://www.newdomain.com/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?olddomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^example-page$ https://www.newdomain.com/somepage [L,R=301]
```

Alternatively, if you are using mod_alias to do the redirecting, then your second redirect needs to be a `RedirectMatch` and not the `Redirect` directive:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/example-page https://www.newdomain.com/somepage
```

Comment: Thank you for this Jon.. Yeah I'll use RedirectMatch for the second one. Main issue was the first one and you solved it :)